# How I would I be able to display the grades?

Tags: c++

I all really need to do is to display the grades, but for some reason I'm having a brain fart and I can't for the life figure it out. For those of you that must know, the entire assignment was that I was given a text file with numbers. Each row would consist of four test scores that equates to one student. I have to calculate the average for each student and display their grade. How would I go on about with the code that I have set up?

Here are the numbers that appear in the text file:

```
44 55 77 88
79 88 100 99
77 99 98 99
100 88 89 100
55 56 40 77
100 100 99 95
88 84 87 88
96 97 99 100
30 44 77 55
79 77 88 0
54 52 60 77
88 77 88 77
44 77 10 95
```

Here is the code

```
// This program calculates a student's average test score, displays
// their grade and then reads the file back to the user.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream testscores; // Creating an object to output file.
    testscores.open("grades.txt"); // Opening the file.

    char grade; // A student's grade.
    int score1, score2, score3, score4; // Four test scores.
    double average; // The average test score for each student.

    cout << "These are the scores and grades for each student.\n\n";
    cout << "Averages           Grade";
    cout <<"\n--------           -----\n";

    if (!testscores) // Checking for errors otherwise.
        cerr << "Error opening file.\n";
    else
    {
        /*A loop that reads each number until it reaches the end of the file */
        while(testscores >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> score4)
        {
            // Calculate the average.
            average = (score1 + score2 +score3 +score4) / 4.0;
            cout << setw(2) << average << endl; // Display the average.
        }
        testscores.close(); // closing the file.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider updating the title to reflect what you're asking about. "Need a bit of guidance" is incredibly non-specific.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what your problem is. You have calculated the average and now you want to compute the grade based on that average?

Comment: yes, I thinking I could use some if/else statements inside the while loop but that is my best guess.

Comment: So, what does the assignment about how you shall compute the grade?

Comment: You mean what is the criteria when it comes outputting the grades? My instructor said to display the grades. I'm just following the traditional grading system. if the average is 90 or above it's an A. if the average is an 80 or above it's B and so on and so forth. I'm not sure if that's what your talking about.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was talking about. This is an essential part of the problem missing in your question: the specification (the algorithm) of how to get from the average to the grade. And it seems, you don't know how to program/implement that algorithm?

Comment: Well, I will attempt at something and I will be back to you momentarily.

Comment: Don't forget to give credit to SO when you turn in your assignment. Check your school's academic honesty policy.

Comment: Of course, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to just display the grade for each student. For that,you could use `if...else` just after you display the `average` of each student.

```
if(average>=90)
grade='A';
if(average<90 && average >=80 )
grade='B';
if(average<80 && average >=70)
grade='C';
// and so on...then print:
cout<<"Grade="<<grade<<endl;
```